# Should I tune string to pitch on attack, or on to the pitch on its sustain phase?

Tags: tuning, string-instruments

When I hit the string with a pick, it's tune becomes higher by a few cents.

Should I tune the string the way that string sounds in pitch when I hit it with the pick, or I should I tune it the way the string is perfectly in pitch when it goes from aroused to more stable state?